# Celery - Activate a task via command line or HTTP requests

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, celery, celery-task, flower

I have a predefined celery task in my code, say `my_proj.tasks.my_celery_task`

I want to activate the task via the command line/HTTP request (not via my application).

I searched the documents (saw flower and curl options) but there isn't a real good example of calling a predefined task there. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming you have installed Celery with Rabbitmq, here is a simple example.

Define a task: **my_app.py**

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Start a worker:

```
celery worker -l info -A my_app
```

Start flower

```
flower -A my_app
```

Add a task to queue via command line

```
curl -X POST -d '{"args":[1,2]}' http://localhost:5555/api/task/async-apply/my_app.add
```

or via requests

```
import requests, json
api_root = 'http://localhost:5555/api'
task_api = '{}/task'.format(api_root)
args = {'args': [1, 2]}
url = '{}/async-apply/my_app.add'.format(task_api)
print(url)
resp = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(args))
reply = resp.json()
reply
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying exactly that but it doesn't return (as if it's stack). Is there anyway to set a timeout to check why it's stack? I'm using the CURL option.

Comment: You can set timeout. A simple example to set it is given here http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/mher/flower/blob/master/docs/api.ipynb

Answer (score 14):

You can use the celery command line

## Call a task

```
# Positional arguments
celery call my_celery_task --args='[1,2]' --broker <broker_url>
# Keyword arguments
celery call my_celery_task --kwargs='{"x":1, "y":2}' --broker <broker_url>
# Returns the task-id
```

## Get the result

```
celery result <task_id> --result-backend <backend_url>
```

---

You should select the same broker and backend set in your celery application.